# How to get started with DirectInput from a Visual Studio 2013 C# solution on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, directx, sharpdx, managed-directx

Following a comment posted to [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159752/keyboard-getkeystates-false-positive-how-do-i-actually-know-if-a-key-is-pressed), I am trying to get started using DirectInput.

I am absolutely unfamiliar with it, and I don't know how to get started at all. The namespace seems to be Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput but I cannot seem to find it anywhere in my references.
It says in several places that you just have to add it from the references in my project but I couldn't find it.
I checked for a DirectX SDK but it seems it is now part of the Windows SDK and the Windows SDK is already installed with Windows 8 so I shouldn't have to do anything?

I found a couple of alternatives, of which SharpDX sounds like a good one. I have not been able to start with this either... I have installed the SharpDx.Input nuGet package but I can't seem to use the code I can find elsewhere, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929764/taking-input-from-a-joystick-with-c-sharp-net).
`new DirectInput()` for instance is not recognized at all by Visual Studio.

Comment: Microsoft doesnt recommend direct input anymore

Comment: @Astro: does that include SharpDX's implementation?

Comment: I actually have't worked with SharpDX. if sharDx has implemented using DirectX, I suppose yeah..

[see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85).aspx)

they say "The use of DirectInput for keyboard and mouse input is not recommended. You should use Windows messages instead."

Comment: @Astro that's a shame because I'm precisely facing an issue with those (cf. the other question linked in this question) and am trying to find an other way of solving this

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn If you post this and I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput" assemblies are Managed DirectX 1.1 and are deprecated. Furthermore, VS 2013 defaults to using .NET 4.x which is not supported by legacy Managed DirectX 1.1. See [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).

The underlying DirectInput component whether used by C# or C++ is legacy and is not recommended for use for mouse or keyboard. For Xbox One and Xbox 360 common controllers, we recommend using XINPUT. To use legacy HID devices (joysticks, PS3 controllers, some haptic controllers, etc.), you still use DirectInput. For XINPUT use on Windows 8.x, see this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/26/xinput-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx). For use from C++, you should look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) particularly the [GamePad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/09/05/directx-tool-kit-now-with-gamepads.aspx) class.